# Spam in product reviews - always on same product

Tags: product-review

We regulary receive spam reviews in Magento, but manually approve/decline reviews so it does not make any harm - other than a few seconds extra work.

But I wonder.. all spam posts are always (without exceptions) related to the same product. I tried to change URL to this product a while ago, but no difference. I know I can delete and create it as a new item.. but I'm a bit querious on why this product only is affected.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: stupid question, but why does it matter? why not takel the spam-problem

Comment: Any stupid question deserves a stupid answer - so I guess we're even then. One way to deal with a problem is to understand what causes it, and work from there. I know I can use CAPTCHA or or use services like Akismet to prevent spam, but as mentioned; this is really not a big problem to me. But I´m curious to know why it´s related to one product only. If you know the answer, feel free to answer. If not, well..

Answer (score 0):

every product url you are cahning is just an entry in the "url_rewrite" table. now there are multiple options:

1. Your old rewrite still exists
2. The attacked uses the target path
3. something else

Answer (score 0):

Check your access logs. If you're not sure where these are get in contact with your host.

Look for anything with product url or entity ID

You know time and date from reviews so that should help you narrow down your search

But essentially you should see the URL they are using and figure out how/why from that. Plus if single IP you could block IP.